# MongoDB Atlas and Mongoose - GET API - need support for - case insensitive query value

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, collation, mongodb-atlas

I've built an API to GET a restaurant returned if i search for it. However it only works if the case matches identically. E.g. My Atlas MongoDB has the pub 'Shovels Inn' stored as 'SHOVELS INN'.

So in Postman, unless i enter 'SHOVELS INN', it will never find the pub e.g. 'shovels inn' fails to get a result. I have 1024 restaurants stored in my DB, so i need to be able to enter any of these restaurant names, with case insensitivity. I've tried indexes, collation, adjusting my schema etc.
Im a newbie so any help much appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

// Make Mongoose use the new unified topology as old one was deprecated
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

// sets an index? Consider removing this
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

// Connect to MongoDB Atlas

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-fmz1k.mongodb.net/tempDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true});

// Create Schema
const restaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  BusinessName: String,
  BusinessType: String,
  RatingValue: Number
});

// Restaurant Model which uses restaurant schema
const Restaurant = mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema);

// Routes - requests targetting all restaurants - returns ALL restaurants//////////////////////////
app.route("/restaurants")

.get(function(req, res){
  Restaurant.find(function(err, foundRestaurants){
    if (!err) {
      res.send(foundRestaurants);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }

  });
});

// Route to return a single restaurant using a collection that has collation - still doesnt work//
app.route("/collates/:restaurantName")

.get(function(req, res){
  Restaurant.findOne({BusinessName: req.params.restaurantName}, function(err, foundRestaurant){
    if (foundRestaurant) {
      res.send(foundRestaurant)
    } else {
      res.send("No restaurants matching that title was found.");
    }
  });
});





// Route to return a rating//
app.route("/restaurants/ratings/:restaurantName")

.get(function(req, res){
  Restaurant.findOne({BusinessName: req.params.restaurantName}, {RatingValue: req.params.restaurantName}, function(err, foundRating){
    if (foundRating) {
      res.send(foundRating)
    } else {
      res.send("No restaurant ratings matching that title was found.");
    }
  });
});

// Route to return a Local Authority//
app.route("/restaurants/localauthority/:localauthorityName")

.get(function(req, res){
  Restaurant.find({LocalAuthorityName: req.params.localauthorityName}, function(err, foundAuthority){
    if (foundAuthority) {
      res.send(foundAuthority)
    } else {
      res.send("No local authority matching that input was found.");
    }
  });
});

// If you go to root, then print 'Hello World!'
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("<h1>Hello World!<h1>");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: How did you create the collation on the collection?

Comment: I went into Studio 3T shell and entered a command to create a new collection with collation. I dont recall the exact command (I tried so many solutions tonight). But if I view the index it looks good - it has collation e.g. caseLevel: true

Comment: for a case insensitive search you want caseLevel: false, and you need to specify the same collation in the find.

Comment: Ok I can change the case level. I didnt figure out how to add the  collation to my find command. Any help here would be great, thanks

Comment: You need to pass 4 arguments to Restaurant.find(), see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: Thanks Joe. When I look at the example from .find() it always mentions 'John/'.  Is there way to specify a wildcard here?                            // executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends', function (err, docs) { })

Comment: Yes, you can get a case insensitive search by either creating the collection with a case insensitive collation, or create an index on `name` with such a collation, then pass the same collation in the options document when you call find.  Restrict which fields are returned by passing a projection document to find.

Comment: @Joe Your suggestions worked great! Thanks, my GET requests now work on both upper and lower case